# Downgrade Doctrine ORm 2.5 to 2.4

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

i want Downgrade Doctrine Orm 2.5 to 2.4 For solve this Error :

```
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
```

Note : My php Version : 5.3 (Doctrine 2.5 needed to php 5.4 and later version)

And write this Code in Composer.json file :

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/common": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*"
    }
}
```

and run composer task in cmd with this Code :

```
composer install
```

**But Composer Download Doctrine 2.5**

How Download Doctrine 2.4 With Composer

Comment: Is this a fresh install or was doctrine 2.5 installed before? If it was installed before try to remove the `vendor/` folder and `composer install` again.

Comment: I before Install , Removed Vendor Folder And composer.lock File But Composer Download Doctrine  2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick test and it downloads 2.4

just put this `composer.json` into a folder an run `composer install`:

#### composer.json

```
{
    "name": "test/test",
    "description": "test",
    "license": "no",
    "require": {
        "doctrine/common": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

As you can see in composer install output, `doctrine/common`, `doctrine/dbal` and `doctrine/orm` are all version 2.4.x. I run the test also with `"preferred-install": "source"` and `"minimum-stability": "dev"` same result.

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.4.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/console (v2.6.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.7)
    Loading from cache

symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/process ()
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log (For using the console logger)
doctrine/orm suggests installing symfony/yaml (If you want to use YAML Metadata Mapping Driver)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Comment: Thanks alot , Work Very Good